# How to get APK signing signature?

Tags: android, certificate, apk, signature

Is there a way to retrieve the signature of the key used to sign an APK? I signed my APK with my key from my keystore. How can I retrieve it programmatically?

Comment: you could use an ant script to sign it. but it will require you to store your passwords somewhere which is unsafe.

Comment: I just need to get signature from my app inside it, e.g. in my first activity I somehow get my app signature. Up to now I don't know how

Comment: ah i understand now. i am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can access the APK's signing signature like this using the PackageManager class
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

```
Signature[] sigs = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
for (Signature sig : sigs)
{
    Trace.i("MyApp", "Signature hashcode : " + sig.hashCode());
}
```

I've used this to compare with the hashcode for my debug key, as a way to identify whether the APK is a debug APK or a release APK.

Comment: how do you know whether it is signed with debug or release key?
I get:
08-08 08:24:36.668: I/Platform(19131): Signature hashcode : -1907392821

I don't even know how to verify whether it is my package or not...
(I need to verify whether com.mypackage.myapp belongs to me or not)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122401/android-compare-signature-of-current-package-with-debug-keystore?rq=1

lets me differentiate between debug or release apk, but is there a way to validate my signature against my public key to verify the apk actually comes from me? Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to get a signature of a not installed application? For example if I have an .apk file

Comment: this approach is not collision resistant

Comment: For serious cases, don't use `hashCode()`. For example, if you want to validate that some other app that you want to communicate with was signed with the right key, use a cryptographically-secure hash (e.g., SHA256).

Comment: @Ruzard Yes, you can. You need to push the not installed apk to the location where you program can get the apk such as SD_CARD, then use context.getPackageManager().getPackageAchiveInfo(NOT_INSTALL_APK_PATH,PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES) .signatures[0] to get its hashCode. and compare them . Good luck

Comment: what does Trace.i() method do..? Somebody please help me understand.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? .hashCode() just returns the Java Object's has code, which is useless to know in this context.

Comment: @CommonsWare shouldn't `hashCode` return the id of the object in memory?

Comment: @HosseinShahdoost: Ummm... yes. Which even further means that you shouldn't use `hashCode()` here. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare well, I asked a question about this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651834/is-signature-hashcode-referring-to-the-right-hashcode/49657447 and apparently they have overwritten the method `Signature.hashCode()`, it returns the hashCode of the signature not the object in memory

Comment: @HosseinShahdoost Yes, they have overwritten it, but it is still not safe to use. The computed hash consists of 32 bits, which allows for trivial collisions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60415924 for details.

Comment: @fhenneke of course, the returned hash shouldn't be used for anything serious but the main problem was that they have decided to override such a fundamental method. I think the whole idea was wrong.

Comment: how to get it using deployment_cert.der?

Comment: need special permission if app targets android >=11. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345805/namenotfoundexception-when-calling-getpackageinfo-on-android-11

Answer (score 35):

The package manager will give you the signing certificate for any installed package.  You can then print out the details of the signing key, e.g.

```
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
final List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

for (PackageInfo p : packageList) {
    final String strName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
    final String strVendor = p.packageName;

    sb.append("<br>" + strName + " / " + strVendor + "<br>");

    final Signature[] arrSignatures = p.signatures;
    for (final Signature sig : arrSignatures) {
        /*
        * Get the X.509 certificate.
        */
        final byte[] rawCert = sig.toByteArray();
        InputStream certStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawCert);

        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
            X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certStream);

            sb.append("Certificate subject: " + x509Cert.getSubjectDN() + "<br>");
            sb.append("Certificate issuer: " + x509Cert.getIssuerDN() + "<br>");
            sb.append("Certificate serial number: " + x509Cert.getSerialNumber() + "<br>");
            sb.append("<br>");
        }
        catch (CertificateException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the command to validate the file with the corresponding serialNumber: unzip -p [path_to_apk] META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert

Answer (score 8):

My situation is that I have a pre-installed apk which use a wrong key-store . So directly install will give a fail because of inconsistent signature.I need to check the signature first to make sure it can be install smoothly.

Here is my **solution**.

As [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579239/4030649) says, you can get the signature from an installed apk.

details:

```
Signature sig = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];
```

Secondly: get the releaseApk hashCode to compare. In my case, I downloaded this apk from my server, and put it in the sd_card.

```
Signature releaseSig = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo("/mnt/sdcard/myReleaseApk.apk", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];
```

Finally,compare the hashCode.

```
return sig.hashCode() == releaseSig.hashCode;
```

I have tried the code above, it works just fine. If the hashCode is different, you should just [uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21854473/4030649) the old apk or if it's a system app and the device is rooted, you can just use runtime to [remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048026/4030649),and then install the new signature apk.

Comment: getPackageArchiveInfo, not getPackageAchiveInfo

Comment: need special permission if app targets android >=11. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345805/namenotfoundexception-when-calling-getpackageinfo-on-android-11