# How to uninstall own app from /system/app?

Tags: android, shell, uninstallation

I'm able to install own application into /system/app using adb shell commands. But how to uninstall it? Is there any commands to do it? My phone is rooted.

Comment: I guess you may like to go through the [link](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Barebones)

Comment: @Relsell link is not available anymore. See [latest working mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20121023222841/http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Barebones/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Manual uninstall using ADB :
http://www.careace.net/2010/05/12/how-to-remove-android-apps-through-adb/

During website downtime (like now) see crawled snapshot here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20180222063358/http://www.careace.net/2010/05/12/how-to-remove-android-apps-through-adb/

Programmatically:

```
    public static void deleteFromSystem (final String file)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (new File(file).exists())
            {
                String  path        = new File(file).getParent();
                Process process     = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes("mount -o rw,remount /system; \n");
                os.writeBytes("chmod 777 "      + path + "; \n");
                os.writeBytes("chmod 777 "      + file + "; \n");
                os.writeBytes("rm -r "          + file + "; \n");
                os.writeBytes("mount -o ro,remount /system; \n");
                os.writeBytes("reboot \n");
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                process.waitFor();
            }
        } 
        catch (Throwable e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: I tried your snippet in my application.The has been removed from home screen.But I have a problem after uninstalling app and then to reinstalling app it manages its sharedpreference state. I need the preferences need to clear.

Comment: This code gives the following IO Exception to me:
Working Directory: null    Environment: null
Yes I used the correct app name.

Comment: @ Campiador  Have you root?

Comment: I think that in the past, it succeeded without restarting. is this the best way to uninstall system apps?

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you have root access to device:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
rm -rf /system/app/myApp.apk
rm -rf /data/data/com.example.myapp
mount -o ro,remount /system
exit
exit
```

Comment: Thank you. you saved my a lot of time!

Answer (score 12):

```
adb shell rm /system/app/MyApp*
adb uninstall org.my.app
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Uninstall Android App via adb**

---

Refer : **[xda](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/)**

```
adb devices

adb shell

pm list packages

pm uninstall -k --user 0 name of package
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if you have to do this on every device (may be it can be achieved just by root access on some devices )  but on htc desire  you have to reboot  to the recovery mode 
Then you can copy your apk to the sdcard and then using adb shell  to the /system/app folder 
you should  create a nandroid backup first

Comment: Im sorry I cant read :D  anyway it should be possible to delete it in the recovery mode

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have root access to device:

adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount/system
rm -rf /system/app/myApp.apk
rm -rf /data/data/com.example.myapp
mount -o ro,remount/system
exit
exit