# Is it possiable to get app signature in iOS and Windows Phone?

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, digital-signature

I know, that in Android I can get app signature [How to get APK signing signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/android-how-to-get-app-signature)

But I need to get signature also in iOS and Windows Phone.

I need this to limit access to api server.