# Flutter android release apk while installing over old version giving app not installed error

Tags: flutter

Previously I have uploaded android native application on play store. Now I want to replace existing application with new flutter application. After signing I uploaded app on play store alpha channel. But while upgrading app giving error app not installed.

Note : I have followed flutter documentation steps while creating apk.

Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but i just had the same problem and found a solution for me.

make sure that:

- both have the same Signed Certificate
- the new App APK has a higher version code then installed app

You can find out which version code your apk has with android studio - build:  analyse apk and look at the AndroidManifest.xml.

As mentioned in https://medium.com/@ralphbergmann/versioning-with-flutter-299869e68af4 the flutterversioncode is taken from the build number in the pubspec.yaml

In my case the version code of the old app was 4, although i did not set any build number in my old pubspec.yaml file.

Changing the version of my app to x.x.x+5 did solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm

1. If both are signed by same certificate use this [command to check certificate details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27709792/1441732) look for validation time of the both the signed apk.
2. If they are indeed signed by same certificate the go to Build>Analyse APK (add path of your signed apk)