# How to compare certificates of two apps

Tags: android, certificate, signature, android-package-managers

Let say that I have different certificates A-certificate and B-certificate, and I sign 3 apps (one with A , and two with B)

How can I check form application signed with certificate B that the other app is also signed with B (not with A)

I need some method that will programmatically check if some app is signed with the same certificate as some other app

the method stub should look like this

```
public boolean sameCertificate(String packagename1,String packagename2){
//some comparison
//return true/false
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way is to not even need to check yourself -- just give both of those apps the same shared user id in your manifests; that way Android will enforce that they must be signed alike.

If you prefer the manual approach, you can get an application's signature using the PackageManager. [How to get APK signing signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/android-how-to-get-app-signature) shows you more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean sameCertificate(Context context, String packageName1, String packageName2) {
    return context.getPackageManager().checkSignatures(packageName1, packageName2) == PackageManager
            .SIGNATURE_MATCH;
}
```