# How to get Signature Key by APK

Tags: android, key, apk

I have lost my signature key of application. I searched everywhere but didn't get the answer. please android experts , suggest me how can I get my signature key, I have APK file.
I visited
[How do I find out which keystore was used to sign an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-to-find-out-which-key-was-used-to-sign-an-app)

I unzipped the APK and extracted the file /META-INF/ANDROID_.RSA (this file may also be CERT.RSA, but there should only be one .RSA file).

but did not get The signature.

Comment: Ollie figured eplained that already in that post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5579239/1965084

Comment: @alex I got Signature Hashcode by your answer. but now how can i create .Keystore file by hashcode? please suggest me

Comment: I don't think you can generate the keystore file from the signature. You can retrieve your lost file with google. Follow this instruction: http://prophetek.com/2011/11/01/how-to-recover-from-lost-android-keystore/