# How to implement Android API security?

Tags: android, facebook, api, security, authentication

I am trying to create an API for Android clients similar to [Google](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

Both Google and Facebook have this process in their API's of generating some kind of hash from your android keystore. They say that only requests made from your `packagename` `(eg. com.example.myapp)` and that keystore's hash will be allowed and identified in their systems as you.

```
Google's method:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path-to-debug-or-production-keystore> -list -v
```

and

```
Facebook:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

How would I implement my API to guarantee secure identifiable requests from the Android client to my backend.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain application signature as it suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/android-how-to-get-app-signature). That you can use [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1) to encode it.

There are many Java libraries for SHA1 and MD5, here is [one](http://www.sha1-online.com/sha1-java/) I googled.

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Comment: @MichaelBarany here you go

Comment: thanks, but I'm just using standard Java. In any case perhaps someone can explain how to use the application signature on requests.

Comment: @MichaelBarany oh sorry, changed the link to java sample