# How to find if two apks are signed with same keys?

Tags: android, signature, android-keystore

I want to know how two different apk files are signed with same key in Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get app signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/how-to-get-app-signature)

Comment: Can't find my answer in the link above...

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Unpack both APKs, and run

> keytool -printcert -file META-INF/yourfile.RSA

Then, compare the fingerprints, if they are the same, the keys were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use PackageManager.getPackageInfo() passing GET_SIGNATURES as the flags for each of the applications.

The PachageInfo.signatures arrays can then be deep compared for equality - that is to say call equals() on each of the corresponding items in the two arrays.