# I want retrieve app signature from APK is it possible?

Tags: android

Is there any way how to retrieve app signature from APK? I signed it with my key from keystore and is there way, how to retrieve it ?

Comment: You can trivially retrieve the *signature* as that is an essential step to verifying it, however, you cannot retrieve the *key* - if you could, the whole exercise of signing it would be pointless.

Comment: This question has been answered here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/how-to-get-app-signature

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, there is **no way** to retrieve signature but for educational purpose you can perform reverse engineering on existing apk and generate apk by applying new signature.

Comment: I want to make some changes and upload it on google play for use if i change the certificate it create any problem ?

Comment: if owner of existing app come to know about it,he/she can sue you for this and also google may deactivate your account if he/she apply for justice.simple :-)