# Prevent phishing Android apps communicating with server

Tags: java, android, servlets, phishing

I have created and published on Google Play an Android app that communicates with my server. I want to check that my server (Java Servlet) only accepts requests from this Android app, so that if someone clones my code and creates a new app, when it tries to communicate with the server, the requests are rejected.

Is there a way to do that? Perhaps with domain names, or signed apps,...? This is to prevent phishing attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can get your app's signing key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/how-to-get-app-signature) and check it on your server, but [someone can get this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331469/how-to-find-out-which-key-was-used-to-sign-an-app). If you use https for your connection, and use proguard, I think it's disincentive enough.

Comment: So with proguard no one can get the signing key of my APK using the technique of the second link?

Comment: They still can get signing key, but can't trace your connection because of https, and can't read your code with decompile (easily) because of proguard