# Is there a way to check whether two apk has the same signature programmatically on Android

Tags: android, apk, signature

Is there a way to know whether the installed application have the same signature as the one begin to install?

Comment: Yes. Been a very long time since I've looked at the code to do this but it's definitely possible. I think the PackageManager is able to give you the signer for an apk but I really can't recall for certain.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/how-to-get-app-signature

Comment: "as the one begin to install?" -- that part, no. Using `PackageManager` to get signatures is possible, but only for installed apps, and *maybe* for an APK that is accessible on the filesystem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the signature of an app using `PackageManager`:

```
Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo("packagename", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
```