# IPA sign Signature like Android

Tags: ios, ipa

I am working on an app where backend team is asking for App-signature.
We can find in Android  as per below link

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/how-to-get-apk-signing-signature)

But I could not (never) find any way to get signature of the app as a hash code.

Please let me know If we can get the signature in iOS SDK.

Sorry If it looks as foolish question.

Comment: Taking a step back: What are you trying to do?