# How to get signature of a sideloaded APK from PackageInstaller

Tags: android, certificate, apk, digital-signature, android-source

I am trying to build a custom Android (based on AOSP 7.1) for a device. I would like to get the signature of apps that is to be sideloaded via USB. The apps are not installed on the system yet. My eventual goal is to compare the signature of an APK vs platform signature like this: https://gist.github.com/scottyab/b849701972d57cf9562e

I found many guides, including this one -
[How to get APK signing signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/how-to-get-apk-signing-signature)

and followed the comment by Shengfeng Li on the accepted answer - "You need to push the not installed apk to the location where you program can get the apk such as SD_CARD, then use `context.getPackageManager().getPackageAchiveInfo(NOT_INSTALL_APK_PATH,PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES) .signatures[0]` to get its hashCode. and compare them"

I am modifying the PackageInstaller app that is in AOSP (https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_packageinstaller/blob/master/src/com/android/packageinstaller/PackageInstallerActivity.java).

I modified the `processPackageUri` function of the `PackageInstallerActivity.java` like this (added `PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES` flag):

```
case SCHEME_FILE: {
    File sourceFile = new File(packageUri.getPath());
    PackageParser.Package parsed = PackageUtil.getPackageInfo(sourceFile);

    // Check for parse errors
    if (parsed == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation");
        showDialogInner(DLG_PACKAGE_ERROR);
        setPmResult(PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK);
        return false;
    }
    mPkgInfo = PackageParser.generatePackageInfo(parsed, null,
            PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS|PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES, 0, 0, null,
            new PackageUserState());

    as = PackageUtil.getAppSnippet(this, mPkgInfo.applicationInfo, sourceFile);
} break;
```

Signature validation function

```
public boolean validateAppSignature() throws NameNotFoundException {
        boolean sigMatch = false;

        try {
            for (Signature signature : mPkgInfo.signatures) {
                // SHA1 the signature
                String sha1 = getSHA1(signature.toByteArray());
                // check if it matches hardcoded value
                sigMatch = PLATFORM_SIGNATURE.equals(sha1);
                if (sigMatch){
                  return sigMatch;  
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return false;

}
```

I hope to get the hash of the signature of the APKs but it is throwing this error, (from adb logcat) 
`W System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

probably from the try part `for (Signature signature : mPkgInfo.signatures)`. I suspect that `PackageParser.generatePackageInfo` part is wrong and it is not returning any signature. Can someone enlighten me please? Thanks a lot.

**Addendum:** I found that the PackageInstaller app was indeed getting no signatures. I traced the codes and found the following in `src/com/android/packageinstaller/PackageUtil.java`:

```
public static PackageParser.Package getPackageInfo(File sourceFile) {
    final PackageParser parser = new PackageParser();
    try {
        return parser.parsePackage(sourceFile, 0);
    } catch (PackageParserException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`parsePackage` function is from `frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java` which like this:

```
public Package parsePackage(File packageFile, int flags) throws PackageParserException {
        if (packageFile.isDirectory()) {
            return parseClusterPackage(packageFile, flags);
        } else {
            return parseMonolithicPackage(packageFile, flags);
        }
    }
```

It accepts flags but `PackageUtil.java` passes no flags to it and I think that's the reason I am not getting any signatures of the apk files. I think I may need to call `collectCertificates(Package, int)` from `PackageParser.java` if I want the signatures.

Am I on the right track? Your inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: Since you're building AOSP from source anyway, put some debug logging in PackageParser.java.  It would appear that the reason this would fail is that there are no signatures to report.   But first verify that it is really returning none (that the NPE isn't coming from something else) and verify that the package is actually signed.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I will try like you suggested.

Comment: Hello @ChrisStratton. I used apktool to find the signature of apk files and they are indeed there. For the record, here is what I did.

I downloaded an APK file. I then created a copy of that apk file and signed it with my own key. I then issued `apktool d cool_app.apk` and then did `keytool -printcert -file CERT_NAME.RSA` to the certificate under META-INF produced by the apktool command. It returned the fingerprints of the apk files. For the one signed with my key, the fingerprint is the same as the one on my certificate. I will now try the PackageParser.java method you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, thanks to the comment by @ChrisStratton. I needed to call `collectCertificates` from `PackageInstallerActivity.java`, like so:

```
case SCHEME_FILE: {
    File sourceFile = new File(packageUri.getPath());

    PackageParser.Package parsed = PackageUtil.getPackageInfoMod(sourceFile, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS|PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

    // Check for parse errors
    if (parsed == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation");
        showDialogInner(DLG_PACKAGE_ERROR);
        setPmResult(PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        try {
            PackageParser.collectCertificates(parsed, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    mPkgInfo = PackageParser.generatePackageInfo(parsed, null,
            PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS|PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES, 0, 0, null,
            new PackageUserState());
    as = PackageUtil.getAppSnippet(this, mPkgInfo.applicationInfo, sourceFile);
} break;
```