# Android, Multiple Apps, Multiple Customers, One Keystore

Tags: android, keystore

I have 15 android apps to build and host (and update in the future).

Each app has a unique package name.

5 apps will be hosted on one google play account.

the other 10 will be on 10 individual customer accounts.

I dont want a link between the apps, and want to be able to update them seperately in the future.

Question: Can I use 1 Keystore for all? Or will I need a unique keystore for each app? Will this effect the update process in the future? Or do I just need to keep packagename the same to make sure of a successful update?

Answer (score 7):

In theory, you can use the same keystore to sign all the applications. In practice, however, it would be good to use individual keystores per developer accounts. The reason being, they belong to different customers and in future, if somebody else have to update the apps (not you), then you will have to either supply the keystore to the customer or update the application by signing with a different keystore. Both of these can be problematic.

Comment: Ah Ok, So this is a matter of future security and good practice rather than a technical problem? So sharing the same keystore across develop account wont link apps in anyway?

Comment: AFAIK, Google Play does only basic checks on the certificate viz., validity period. You could read the implications of a shared key in ["Securing Your Private Key"](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#secure-key)

Comment: How about having a single keystore, but one key (and alias) for each developer account? Then you could just export the key to someone else who have to update the app, right?

Comment: Haven't really tried that. But it looks feasible.