# Same Keystore for different app

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have used always the same keystore and same alias key for all published app...

This is a right choice, or Should I use a different alias for each published app?

I haven't find really clear informations about the right use of keystore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keystore file, or signing of the apps, represent that some developer or company certify that application has been developed or verified by that particular company or developer, not the application itself.

So, as far you are developing the app, with name of your company, or yours, you should sign app with same keystore, though not mandatory.

Comment: Omg. So far I always use different keystore. One keystore for one app.

Comment: Assume you have 2 apps, signed with same keystore. If you sell one of your apps to another party - then you will also be giving away the common keystore. So not sure, how that would play out.

Comment: Not mandatory. And not always a good idea, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26186004/165164

Answer (score 3):

You can use same keystore for signing multiple applications.

There is no need to create new keystore file again and again.

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685458/can-i-use-the-same-keystore-file-to-sign-2-applications) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing a keystore between multiple applications is a bad idea and isn't very secure.

1. API Consoles that use a keystore for identification can get messy.
2. If one app keystore is compromised, all apps are compromised

Comment: Does this still apply with regards to the new automatic app-signing that most platforms have started using?