# Android - Can Publish different Apps with same keystore file in multiple Accounts?

Tags: java, android, google-play, keystore

I have uploaded signed `apk` file with `keystore` in Client `Developer Account`. Now i have an another application from the same client with different Developer Account. Can i upload signed `apk` file with the same `keystore` file or shall i use new `keystore` file? Please Help me...

Comment: Yes, as long as the package name is different.

Comment: ok @User117 "Yes" meaning i can upload different signed apk files(of course, package name is different) with same keystore in different developer accounts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Key Store has a collection of digital certificates, which are unique to a publisher, like your signature. They are used to verify that Apps come from a genuine source.

Package name + signature combo must be unique, i.e. one App can't have multiple official publishers:

1. Device won't update same App package with different signature.
2. Play store won't let you update same package file with different signature.

but a publisher can publish multiple apps:

1. Device can have many Apps with different package names but same signature.
2. Play Store can host many apps with different package but same signature.

Apart from that, each Play Store Account is given a unique Licence key, unlike signature, its bound to the Account. You can't use one Account's Licence Key for an app published from other account.

As far as Google policy is concerned, I don't think they limit 1 signature per developer account as of now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same keystore in as many apps as you like, across as many accounts as you want, as long as all your apps have a unique package name.

Comment: And for 'Alias', what should i write?

Answer (score 1):

Yes using same `keystore` you can publish app in different Developer Account.