# Convert currently released android app to flutter build

Tags: flutter, signed-apk, flutter-packages

I currently have an Android app which I'm going to rebuild in flutter. (I would really like to just start with a clean slate in the code base, but don't want to loose installs/current backend Google play subscription integration already set up and associated with the current store listing.)

My question is do I have to add a flutter module to the existing build, or can I start from scratch, rebuild it and then upload the generated flutter (android apk) to the play store, or will it not let me because it is a different package?

If I use the same Package name and Keystore as the original android apk, will Google play allow it?

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14973468/10205629, since flutter is integrated with gradle and native android the same applies. Google Play will indeed let you publish your app if you have the same Package name, and the same  Keystore . The problem comes if you have data on that previous app , you will need to import that data to flutter via native communication . For that i would suggest using a different version to start from scratch

Comment: Thanks, that answers it. My backend is 100% cloud so I'm not worried about the local data.