# Android Api Key

Tags: android

I have Android Apps A and B waiting to be published on Android Play-store.Is it possible to keep same fingerprint for multiple Apps, with different package names?

This is to allow Just  one of the two Apps to be installable in a supporting device. How to do this

I could use the same fingerprint to publish apps in Play-Store. But I was able to do an Install of both the Apps on the same phone.This is not what was intended. Any Solution ?

Comment: Yes you can.
have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685458/can-i-use-the-same-keystore-file-to-sign-two-different-applications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use the same keystore file to sign two different applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685458/can-i-use-the-same-keystore-file-to-sign-two-different-applications)

Comment: Does that mean that If App-A is already installed then it would somehow restrict installation of App-B or prompt user about it..Say, App A and B are related so i need users to install only one..That is what is required

Answer (score 0):

The *application ID* is what distinguishes apps on your device and in Google Play. I don't think it is possible to force only one app to be installed at a time if they have different application ID. Android has an "application ID" which is used to uniquely identify your app. It has nothing to do with what keystore is used to sign the APK.

But, the application ID is not necessarily the package name. An excerpt from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html):

> Although your project's package name matches the application ID by default, you can change it. However, if you want to change your package name, be aware that the package name (as defined by your project directory structure) should always match the package attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file

So you can have two different apps with the same application ID, but different package names. And then only one of them could be installed on a device. I'm not sure if that's what you're going for, though.

And I'm not sure that your reasoning for doing this is great. Maybe you can expand upon what you mean by

> This is to allow Just one of the two Apps to be installable in a supporting device.

so that maybe someone can suggest a better alternative for your situation.

Comment: Ok , this is perhaps closest to the answer I am looking for .I need to verify the same.
Apps A&B are related so I do not want a user to install both at a time.