# Uploading Android App Bundle to Google Play Console - key signing error

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload a brand new .aab file to the Google Play Console, but keep getting this error:

> **Upload failed**
>   You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed
>   with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users.
>   Because you are enrolled in App Signing by Google Play, you should
>   sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload
>   it.

I'm completely stumped, as I generated a new key for this app bundle at the time of generating the app bundle, i.e. through the Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK... menu item in Android Studio, so it is a brand new key, unused by other apps.
I've even tried creating a whole new keystore with a new key in it, but always get the same error. Is this some quirk someone else has come across?

When enrolling for App Signing by Google Play for this app, I chose the **"Let Google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)"** option, and from all the documentation I've read, the key that you use to sign the app with first becomes the "Upload Key", so it seems like I'm doing everything correctly, but no dice.

Does anyone have any advice, or past experience on this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, after a lot of screaming and shouting, including reaching out to Google Play Console support in chat (they're only first level support, so... not much help) and email (who put me in the too hard basket and said they can't offer support for app development - what? the problem is to do with uploading an app to Play Console, not app dev!), I discovered this self answered question https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359729/845205.

Basically, make sure you're doing a Clean & Rebuild Project whenever doing *anything* to do with signing in Android Studio. For some reason it thought my new app was using the key from my old app and kept signing with that. (I guess the solution was app development support after all!)

Comment: thank you, I had the same issue, just did project -> clean then I created a new signed bundle, uploaded it to the store and had no issues! Gradle cache is a weird thing.

Comment: what if the key we used lately different from the previous one? how to switch that one?

Answer (score 149):

I am facing the same issues,  in my case `signingConfig` was setup, I made one simple mistake, that I forget to change app debuggable to **false**. so even though I generated from menu or from  gradle command, build was successfully generated but it was debuggable so play store not accepting signed apk and give me and message like `Upload Failed The Android Bundle was not Signed in` .

Comment: i also face this issue i add this line `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` in android > app> build.gradle > `{buildType{release{ signingConfig signingConfigs.release }}}`

Comment: This is correct for my case I forgot that in my app level gradle file `buildTypes` `release` debuggable was still set to true.

Comment: Wow... I was battling with this FOREVER! Thank you so much, setting debuggable to false fixed it

Comment: In my case, I don't have debuggable set at all in my build.gradle file (not true or false, the property doesn't exist). I don't even have the buildTypes or release properties. Any idea on why this is?

Comment: Create "New Key Store", signed your apk/app bundle and upload it

Comment: In case your gradle file is a Kotlin script (`.kts`) - the syntax is `isDebuggable = false`

Answer (score 49):

make sure to change app debuggable to false in `build.gradle` file

[image]

Comment: Wondering why Android Studio doesn't show any kind of warning because of this...

Answer (score 15):

*"through the Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK... menu item in Android Studio, so it is a brand new key, unused by other apps."*

Not really. The keystore that Android Studio uses is associated with the Android SDK installation, so all the apps created from your Studio are signed with the same key.

What happened is that you must have created another app, signed it with that keystore, and uploaded it to the Play Console, thus making it a key used to sign APKs served to end users. At the same time, you created another app which you enrolled in Play Signing: for this app, the upload certificate is extracted from the first APK you upload. Since you signed that APK with Studio as well, the same keystore was used. Play detected that it was the same certificate for both those apps, and since you used the same key for two different purposes (app signing key for your first app, and upload key for your second app), Play rejected it. The reason is that an app signing key is much more important than an upload key (the latter can be reset while the first one can't), so you shouldn't use them for two different purposes.

In other words, you'll need to create a different keystore to sign your apps enrolled in Play Signing (ideally, one per app), and make sure you never use that keystore as an app signing key for another app.

Comment: **"In other words, you'll need to create a different keystore to sign your apps enrolled in Play Signing (ideally, one per app), and make sure you never use that keystore as an app signing key for another app."**  


That's what I meant by **"I've even tried creating a whole new keystore with a new key in it, but always get the same error."**  

Brand new keystore, brand new key, never even got close to another app. Still the same error.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure the issue is on your end: you either didn't actually create a new keystore, or you didn't upload the APK that was signed with the new keystore. If you're convinced otherwise and think that there is a bug in the Play Console, I would suggest to reach out to their support (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en-GB#topic=3450769&contact=1 -- they even have a chat line), where they can look into the particular case more in details.

Comment: I confirm that Pierre is right, it works by using a new key that it's not used by any other app. You can also create a new alias in the same keystore to avoid creating another key.

Answer (score 10):

I hit this error in our apps. We use the same upload key for all of our apps.

So when you create a new app, make sure you select the option `Use an existing key that you sign an app with` instead of the `(Google recommended)` option which is to send them an unique upload key.

The really annoying part is that this option can only be selected once, so we had to delete our app and recreate it.

Answer (score 8):

The solution for me turned out to be a matter of changing *the build variant*.

To recap, when I tried to upload my signed .aab bundle file into the Google Play Console for developers, I received this error ***The Android App Bundle was not signed.***

Keep in mind that this error is ambiguous and could be caused by a number of issues as visible in the other answers on this page. I had originally uploaded my app using the `release` build variant. Forgetting what variant I had used originally, I tried to upload the `debug` build variant and got this error.

**My fix**: Upload the same build variant as the original one. They must match!

Comment: What's the different between your debug and release variant? What cause your release  variant doesn't work?

Comment: It's that Google is expecting the new version to replace the old one with the same variant. @BabyishTank

Comment: Thank you, that was also my problem. This error message is extremely misguiding. I sent a feedback to Google.

Comment: @Zwyx yes, I completely agree and if Google could be more descriptive in the error, it would make it so much faster to discover the source of our mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

The following solution worked for me. Add following two lines to your gradle file.

```
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        **signingConfig
        debuggable = false**
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I have

> debuggable true

in. the correct value is **false**

```
buildTypes
     {
         release {
```

Comment: Where is this? What file?

Answer (score 4):

Try removing everything about the new app from console, then start by generating a new key and rebuilding the app with the new key. Then you can re upload the new apk.

Answer (score 3):

The other way this can happen is if you have a signingConfig set up in the app build.gradle. It doesn't seem to matter what you specify in the signing section when you're making a bundle - even if you make a new one or choose some other keystore - it will use the one specified in the gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

i also face this issue i add this line `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` in android > app> build.gradle > `{buildType{release{ signingConfig signingConfigs.release }}}`

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, i solved it by removing my app and adding it again to play console.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I was choosing the *debug* folder instead of release folder in my project as the destination for the Android App Bundle.

I needed the App Bundle for internal testing so I guess that's why it came natural to me to choose it.

Answer (score 1):

After reading  :https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-your-first-app-bundle-bbcd228bf631
I choose to sign it by myself

.//gradlew bundleDebug --project-dir= --stacktrace

jarsigner -keystore .//app/keystore.jks .//app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab key0

Give it the password and voila.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old issue but since i just hit this problem and my solution is not listed, i want to share it so it can help some future stackies.

My problem with signing the app was the entry `testCoverageEnabled true`
which was inside the

```
buildTypes{ release { ... }}
```

even though `debuggable false` was set, googles error message was `Upload Failed The Android Bundle was not Signed` or `debuggable version was uploaded`

setting the testCoverageEnabled flag to false fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

was facing similar issue when uploading aab to playstore from CI/CD, add

> signingConfig signingConfigs.release

in release config as follows

```
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

make sure you have included signing configs in build.gradle as follows

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("$projectDir/dummy.keystore")
        keyAlias 'dummyAlias'
        storePassword 'dummyPassword'
        keyPassword 'dummyPassword'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with a project that has many apps and many kotlin libraries. All those apps have dependencies to those kotlin libraries, so this is reasonable configuration.
When I released first app in Play Console I created keystore and one key that I used with this first app. When I tried to release second app I got this error. There was nothing bad with signing configuration. To get second app released I had to make second key to keystore and sign second apps bundle this this second key.

So it seems that with current Google's signing policy, all released apps need their own signing key. With my experience they can live in same keystore.

Error message "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in App Signing by Google Play, you should sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload it." is very confusing about the situations, but advice how to fix problem was exact right, I has to create new signing key for second app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was working on Godot Engine.
The solution was to uncheck the Export with debug option while saving the .aab file
Assuming you've already put in the release.keystore with user and password in the export dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occur if app bundle is not crated for release, if you select debug option play store will not accept the bundle.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBB1D.png)

Answer (score -3):

Just create a new key, and it should upload.

Comment: Isn't that what OP already tried? They say `I've even tried creating a whole new keystore with a new key in it, but always get the same error.`

Comment: This is undesirable because it puts additional burden on the developer to manage keys and keystores.

Comment: Seems that this error message is got about two very different situations.  If your release build configuration has errors, your bundle can be signed with debug key even if Android studio's UI shows that you use release key. This situation can't be corrected generating key key and using it signing your app bundle

But if build configuration is correct but your are releasing app using key that is used in another released app, your have to create new key for this new app. At least with a android studio project including many apps, this was only solutions to get apps released.