# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-signing

okay, so before I typed this, I have checked out all solutions on StackOverflow regarding my issue and I have tried the following :

1. clean and rebuild
2. incrementing the version code and the version name
3. made sure I have  uploaded the bundle to the correct app in the play console
4. made sure the app Gradle has all the correct info of the key
5. restart AS
6. nothing related to debug is on the release build variant
7. and LAST but not least request for a new key, clean and rebuild, and still doesn't work.

what I did do on this new build:
I did pull the old code form a pervious branch and continued some work on it, is this somehow impacting the key issue?

[error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Veu.png)

Comment: As the error says the SHA1  key is not correct did you check the SHA1 key whether it is the same from the previous branch or not? @shane

Comment: no, I haven't checked if it's the same form the previous batch @BrahmaDatta, and what steps should I take if it's not the same?

Comment: SHA1 is generated in the Android studio where it has unique code that is used for some features like for me I used firebase to make unique keys. So just make sure the SHA1 is matching with the app or not. If not then delete the SHA1 where the error is showing generate new one and try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GooglePlay - wrong signing key for app bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314838/googleplay-wrong-signing-key-for-app-bundle)