# Google playstore abb file issue

Tags: android, react-native, deployment, devops

[Image of play store console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd4ii.png)

can someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your app is not signed. A few answers that may help you

- https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing
- [GooglePlay - wrong signing key for app bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314838/googleplay-wrong-signing-key-for-app-bundle)