# Get Two Signed APK From Same Android Project

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app which includes ads with package name `com.test1`

I got one signed apk from this and I also want another one with package name `com.test1.test2` which will be paid version (directs to google play store).

How can I get second signed apk without using same keystore?

Comment: Make new keystore

Comment: With previous keystore, I will only be able to sign that previous project, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685458/can-i-use-the-same-keystore-file-to-sign-two-different-applications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the same keystore file to sign two different applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685458/can-i-use-the-same-keystore-file-to-sign-two-different-applications)

Comment: Why don't you want to use the same keystore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a package is different then you can choose different Keystore files while generating a new apk.