# Android signing concepts

Tags: android, sign

I know how sign my application and do those practical stuff. But I was once demonstrating to my friend and got stuck in concepts.
what is the difference between:
1- Keystore
2- Key
3- Certificate

what is used to generate what? what is used for the signing process? what are the details?
is there any link for this matter? I've tried http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html but I didn't get the full idea :S

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer in [Understanding keystore, certificates and alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724631/understanding-keystore-certificates-and-alias)

a very good reference would be: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html