# How to generate key hash for Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, keytool

I can open up Key Tool but when I try to enter the command, I encounter my problem.  I am supposed to enter:

keytool -exportcert -alias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

But I am not sure what RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS and RELEASE_KEY_PATH mean?  What should I substitute for them?  Looking for a detailed explanation of both, Thanks!

-Also I am on a Mac

Comment: here is a good explanation im not sure about Mac specifically i know how to get a keyhash for facebook on windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724631/understanding-keystore-certificates-and-alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [this](http://www.4shared.com/zip/HyFFN9rE/keyhash.html) and after extracting it, import it into your Eclipse and then run this in your android device. This way a unique keyHash will be generated for you. The keyHash will appear in your device when you run this.