# openssl:Error: 'g√╓çtΩ┤N▀Kptε╫π∞' is an invalid command

Tags: android, facebook, openssl

I'm trying to create a hash key for my android app for facebook intergration

I've gone to the directory where the keytool is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin
```

I've used the following command to to try to generate the key:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore |
    C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary |
    C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64
```

However, I get the error after entering a password

```
openssl:Error: 'g√╓çtΩ┤N▀Kptε╫π∞' is an invalid command.
```

I've noted the command changes depending on the password. If I leave the password empty I get

```
openssl:Error: '\Fà»T' is an invalid command.
```

I'm using android 2.3.3

Any advice or help would be appreciated as I'm stumped and have found nothing online

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in the present day who might be running into this, make sure **base64** is included at the end of the command. it is getting cut off when I paste the command into my terminal. So it should look like this:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Answer (score 0):

This previous question can be useful for your case:

[RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS and RELEASE_KEY_PATH values for generating key hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049896/release-key-alias-and-release-key-path-values-for-generating-key-hash/50694147#50694147)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The issue was because I was running the command in the wrong directory. Use the folder that has java/bin
Initially I used C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
After solving I used C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin