# Change in Alias name in Keystore in Android

Tags: android

I have release keystore created using Android studio. It is saved as myapp.jks. Using this have uploaded my App to playstore.

Question: Can I change the Alias name and still upload to playstore with an upgrade to version code? Will playstore allow me to do it?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you are able to change Alias Name in key store.

If you are using the same key store for signing your application before pushing it to the play store, it should be fine. Changing Key store's password or alias password doesn't affect the way it is used to generate the signed APK.

[Understanding keystore, certificates and alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724912/1168654)

Comment: So you are saying if I change the alias name in the keystore will not affect the signed APK...? The why do we use the keystore. I thought this is very important if I use a different keystore or alias we will have a issue.

Comment: I have the same question, if I regen the keystore but don't want to use the alias name `upload`, will it be a problem when upload to keystore ?

Comment: Changing the alias name from the 'same keystore file' actually will give affect the file itself and marked by google a wrong key (different from previous)