# Trying to rename a package in Android Studio but says file (com) already exists

Tags: android, apk, keystore

I created a new app in Android Studio, everything went fine, I created a signed apk, but I have an old app on Play Store published, I managed to locate the key.keystore for that old app, which i originally did in Eclipse two years ago, so after opening my old apk in Keystore Explorer, I was able to remember my old store password, alias and key password, so I went back into Android Studio, clicked Generate New Signed apk, I selected my old keystore path, filled in the info (store password, alias, key password, and it left me generate the new signed apk with the old key.keystore, so I'm assuming I actually got the new AS app signed with my old Eclipse key.keystore or it wouldn't have left me generate a signed apk right? or run it in emulator until I entered the correct info.

Now the next problem I'm having is renaming the package, what I need to do is rename the new app/package to the same name as the old app/package (com.name.radio) I read that you do this in the build.gradle..... When I created my new app in AS I was able to renam the 3 folders under java first with no problems (to name.ie.radio) to do this I select the folder I want to rename, click Show Options Menu, untick Compact Empty Middle Packages, right click my folder & select Refactor > Rename > Rename Package, then I had to correct that in the build.gradle, worked fine the first time.

Now I want to rename my new app / package again, to the same name as my old app (com.name.radio) so I tried setting new package name to com, but it doesn't allow me, saying that file already exists. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNgA5.png

Should I delete the com folder at: \app\build\generated\source\r\release
There's no point in trying to rename it in the build.gradle yet right?

Someone help me out here it's like a guessing every night. I just want to publish an update to my old app without having to publish a fresh app.

Answer (score 5):

This modification needs three steps :

1. Change the package name in the manifest
2. Refactor the name of your package with right click -> refactor -> rename in the tree view, then Android studio will display a window, select "rename package"
3. Change manually the application Id in the build.gradle file : android / defaultconfig / application ID Then clean / rebuild the project

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081300/renaming-android-package-name-using-android-studio)

Comment: It won't let me refactor the package name to "com" says that file already exists. http://i.stack.imgur.com/cNgA5.png  It has to be renamed to "com" as that's the name of the old app package (com.name.radio) I re-edited my post above.

Comment: I renamed the "com" directory to "org" \app\build\generated\source\r\release\com

Then I was able to refactor > rename the package name to "com"

Comment: Glad you did it at the end.

Comment: Thanks yea, took a while to figure out after hours of reading.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is delete the directory which Android Studio says is causing the problem. In this case, the `...\build\generated\source\r\release\com` directory.

It will not affect your source code since this is a directory which is automatically generated when you rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
com.yourdomain.yourapp
```

If you cant rename `yourdomain`, rename first the `com` package, then you can raname `yourdomain` and restore the name `com`