# How to change .jks file for my app? I want to change both passwords

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keystore, jks

I want to create new keystore file for my app. Is it possible?

Comment: You are looking for KeyStore or TrustStore?  Request you to please add more details in question.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal
The .jks file that's required to generate apk and aab

Comment: Yes that is possible, you are refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/47565937/7871511 to generate custom Keystore/truststore