# Is it possible to archive a current store listing re-upload an apk to a new store listing

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

Long story short, I lost the password to my alias in my keystore. I have the master password, but the password to one of my aliases inside is long gone.

I've had an app on the playstore, in the beta channel, for a close to a year now (it's never been released to production). This app is signed with that alias and I have no way to update it now.

I've tried brute forcing the keystore, I've tried dictionary attacks, etc. I've also tried adding custom keywords to the dictionary attack that I KNOW would be in the password, but I can't crack it.

The only thing left I can think to do is to take the store listing down, repackage my app (since google only allows one store listing to ever use that package name) and upload it to a new store listing using a brand new keystore.
Is it that simple though? Am I missing anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724631/understanding-keystore-certificates-and-alias/5724912#5724912

Answer (score 0):

That approach will work fine.  Just make sure to back up your keystore and its password this time!

Answer (score 0):

That will work fine. But this time, I'd recommend signing up with [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

Then if it happens again you can contact Google Play support and they can update your upload key for you.