# apk upload failed saying that key store has been changed, but key store hasn't been changed

Tags: android, release, keystore

I have created a release apk for play store update which has been failed to be updated. error saying that key store has been changed, But in fact key store has not been changed.Then create one more release apk and then i tried to upload, It was successfully uploaded this time.

Could anybody let me know the reasons for this error and how to prevent then in future.

Answer (score 0):

Old solution keep the keystore somewhere safe with all the internal aliases. If you by mistake chose a different alias in the keystore this error could

Read following
[Keystore and Aliases - is there a use to multiple aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667399/keystore-and-aliases-is-there-a-use-to-multiple-aliases)

Safer option, use Google Plays's app signing.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en